# How to import an Image to Project resource folder

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm developing a java based application using NetBeans.
What i want to do:

My project folder includes a resources folder which contains all the Images that are needed by the project for basic stuff (setting background,icons etc).
Now suppose end user wants to save an new Image on the run time. File Chooser opens up. User selects a source(.jpg) file and the image gets copied. What i want is, to save this image to my resources folder rather than on LocalDisk path. I'm having no trouble copying this image to a LocalDisk path.
Is there any way through which i can do this?
My resource folder path is:
(ProjectName)\src\resources

Code I'm using to save image to Local Address:

```
InputStream input = null;
OutputStream output = null;
String fileName = itemId.getText();
try
{
    input = new FileInputStream(srcPath.getText()); //Getting Source File Absolute Path Through FileChooser
    output = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\BUN\\Documents\\Folder\\"+fileName+".jpg");
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    int bytesRead;
    while((bytesRead = input.read(buf))>0)
    {
        output.write(buf,0,bytesRead);
    }
}
catch(IOException ex)
{
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Thank's in advance!

Comment: You should not do that. It is possible to do this, but when you will deploy your app in zip (or any other method) file, then it will not be possible for you to add image in it.

Comment: Do you still want to add image in that folder?

Comment: @afzalex Yup, i want to. Despite of the fact that i won't be able to add anything in the future.

Comment: @afzalex Also, exactly why i won't be able to add anything after i've deployed my app to another machine?

Comment: because it will be deployed in a jar file. and you cannot simply add any file inside that jar file.